# I want to get bit of char on MPLAB XC8 but I can't?

Tags: c, mplab, xc8

My function to get bit is:

```
extern volatile unsigned char Temp       @ 0x036;
extern volatile __bit W       @ (((unsigned) &Temp)*8) + 4;

void get_bit(volatile unsigned char *reg, unsigned num) {
    W = (*reg & (1 << num));
}
```

Main function is:

```
int main() {
    volatile unsigned char ch = 0b00001000;
    get_bit(&ch, 4);
}
```

When I compile this code of blocks I get an error (error: expression syntax).

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Where the value of `W` goes (and where it is defined?)?

Comment: Which is line 195?

Comment: Are you expecting a 1 as output? Or a 8? You will always get a 0. Because 1<<4 is 0b010000. And that is assuming that there is such a thing as a binary constant. 0b010000 & 0b01000 is 0.

Comment: My code is wery big so line 195 is not important.

Comment: @BahtiyarBayram The line number where the error is is definitely important.

Comment: I am expecting get bit of char (1 or 0) with get_bit() bunction.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The number point to get_bit(&ch, 4); line.

Comment: Horrible programming style. Difficult to be optimised by the compiler, full of the side effects. Why not in get bit  return (*reg & (1<<num));. And in the main W = get_nit(.....);

And your code will be optimised just to W=0;

Comment: I made up a program from your incomplete post, using `volatile int W;` and get clean compilation and execution from MSVC.

Comment: @Yunnosch I changed this code (W = (*reg & (1 << num));) to this (W = (*reg & (1 << (num-1)));). But error is still exist.

Comment: I am pretty sure the error is *not* where you think it is...

Comment: @EugeneSh. look this picture: [link] (https://ibb.co/cUAGkF) . This code is simple but in my complex code the error on line which I said.

Comment: "Can't generate code for this expression" is meaning something else than "expression syntax". It is likely something to do with the definition of `W`. It is defined using XC8 specific syntax. For testing try defining it as in standard C, something like `int W;`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You are right. I did what you say and everything was good and I had not any problems. But I want to save 1 bit in __bit variable. How can I do that?

Comment: I would start by removing the `extern` things. These seem suspicious to me.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I removed this thing but error still exist.

Comment: I solved that. I did very silly mistake. Guess what? I forgot to put semicolon in somewher. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char get_bit(unsigned char reg, unsigned num) 
{
    return (reg & (1 << num));
}

unsigned char get_bit2(unsigned char reg, unsigned num) 
{
    return (reg & (1 << num))?1:0;
}

int main() 
{
    volatile unsigned char ch = 0b00001000;

    ch |= (1<<4);   // To set bit 4
    printf("%d\n",get_bit(ch, 4)); // If you try on a PC
    printf("%d\n",get_bit2(ch, 4)); // If you try on a PC

    ch &= (~(1<<4));   // To reset bit 4
    printf("%d\n",get_bit(ch, 4)); // If you try on a PC
    printf("%d\n",get_bit2(ch, 4)); // If you try on a PC


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _return (reg & (1 << num))?1:0_????  return !!(reg & (1 << num)) - easy to optimize.

Comment: I want to use pointers because in future I would chance state of bit.

Comment: @BahtiyarBayram. To set the bit you may just use `ch |= (1<<4)` as in my code, but using an unsigned char * instead an unsigned char: `volatile unsigned char *ch; *ch |= (1<<bitpos);`. I suggest you to create set, reset and get functions (or macros, I think is better) to manage the bit operations.

Comment: @BahtiyarBayram. `(cond)?iftrue:iffalse` is  a ternary operator. This operator returns the value `iftrue` if cond is true, otherwise it returns the value `iffalse`. The function `get_bit2()` returns 1 if the bit indicated by `num` is set 1, 0 if the bit indicated by `num` is set 0. The function `get_bit()` returns `(1<<num)` if the bit is set 1, otherwise it returns 0.

Comment: @BahtiyarBayram. Obviously, when you use `volatile unsigned char *`, before to operate like `*ch |= (1<<num)`, you have to set ch value to point the opportune register/memory: `ch = regmemval`.